# getting all parameters are null in dictionary while i am sending those parameters

Tags: ios, iphone

My sign up page by using mysql getting all parameters are null in dictionary, while i am sending those parameters help me anything wrong for code

```
NSString *postData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@&firstName=%@&lastName=%@&dateOfBirth=%@&device_id=%@&latlng=%@&platform=ios",self.emailTextField.text,self.passWordTextField.text,self.firstNameTextField.text,self.lastNameTextField.text,self.dateOfBirthTextField.text,[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"token"],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",latitude,longitude]];

HttpRequest *request = [[HttpRequest alloc] init];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^
{
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [request makeRequestWithURL:mob_app_signup
                                                       and:postData];

    NSLog(@"user Sign UP dictionary %@",dictionary);
    NSString *message = dictionary[@"message"];
    NSString *success=dictionary[@"success"];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [loader removeLoader];
        [self.signUpActionButton setEnabled:YES];
        if (dictionary.count==0)
        {}

        if ([message isEqualToString:@"Signup successfully"] || [success intValue]==1 )
        {
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:dictionary[@"userid"] forKey:@"userID"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:self.emailTextField.text forKey:@"email"];
            //[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:dictionary[@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:self.passWordTextField.text forKey:@"password"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:self.firstNameTextField.text forKey:@"firstName"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:self.lastNameTextField.text forKey:@"lastName"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:self.dateOfBirthTextField.text forKey:@"dateOfBirth"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
            //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"signUpToVerifyMobile" sender:self];

        [self parseData];

        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Which dictionary are you referring to? Is HttpRequest some custom / third party library class?

Comment: Thanks for your response..

Comment: yeah HttpRequest// 
   HttpRequest *request = [[HttpRequest alloc] init];dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^
    
    {
        NSDictionary *dictionary = [request makeRequestWithURL:mob_app_signup
                                                           and:postData];

        NSLog(@"user Sign UP dictionary %@",dictionary);
        NSString *message = dictionary[@"message"];
        NSString *success=dictionary[@"success"];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^

Comment: Your question is Still not clear.